# What is the time complexity if i converted HashSet to TreeSet

Tags: java, android, time-complexity, hashset, treeset

If i want to create a new TreeSet by using the constuctor what would be the time complexity in this case?

```
HashSet<Integer> hashSet = new HashSet<>();

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){

    hashSet.add(arr[i]);

}

TreeSet<Integer> treeSet = new TreeSet<>(hashSet);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `TreeSet(Collection)` constructor simply adds each element one at a time -- and adding each element, as usual for a `TreeSet`, takes O(log n).  Therefore, the whole operation takes O(n log n).